# Enter 100 numbers. Determine which number is more: positive or negative

Tags: java

so i have this homework where i have to enter 100 numbers and after that it determines if its positive or negative, been trying for hours but still unsuccesful.

Enter 100 numbers. Determine which number is more: positive or negative. (This is literally the task and nothing more is written)

Comment: Trying for hours? What exactly have you tried? With which part are you stuck?

Comment: Do you already know how to read numbers from the input? Does that part work?

Comment: Your teacher expects you to manually enter 100 numbers?

Answer (score 2):

When approaching a problem, first think it thru.  Then write the code.

1. initialize a positive or negative counter.
2. start reading in numbers
3. increment the counter based on the number's sign.
4. continue with (2) until 100 numbers have been read.
5. Print out informative information based on the results of the contents of (1) and the count of numbers read.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just trying to find the highest magnitude of either positive or negative numbers you can do this quite easily by checking the absolute value:

```
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;

public class MyClass
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        int randomNum = 0;
        int largestMagnitude = 0;
        
        for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            randomNum = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(-1000, 1000);
            if(Math.abs(randomNum) > Math.abs(largestMagnitude))
            {
                largestMagnitude = randomNum;
            }
        }
        
        System.out.println("The highest magnitude of number generated was " + largestMagnitude);
    }
}
```

Comment: He/she is still learning to code. I don't think you should have posted only the code. You should have told the peson how it actually works.

Answer (score 0):

This is an suggestion to people providing answers. When the problem is a homework (as the OP CLEARLY indicated) it is important to ask what are they currently learning in order to properly frame the answer to the lesson. Basically, the most correct answer for industry might not (and often it is not) the most correct answer for what it is being taught.

@Janis Klein, what you are covering in class at the moment is very important. For example, if you are learning about sorting, the answer might be to implement some sort of sorting algorithm. When you sort a collection of numbers, the most negative and the most positive will be the head and tail values in your sorted collection. If you are learning about lists and collections, the answer might be to implement some sort of linked list where the numbers are inserted in natural order (no need to sort). Like in my previous example, once you insert all 100 values into this list, the head and tail values are the most positive and negative values.

However, if all you are learning is to do comparisons of values, you don't need but two variables (one for most positive and one for most negative) and all you will need to do is to compare incoming values and store them into the correct variable if needed. For example, the very first value will be both the most positive and most negative. The second incoming value will be either the most positive or most negative (assuming unique values are always received). From the third value on, the incoming value MIGHT be the most positive, the most negative, or simply neither; in which case, the incoming value is discarded. In the end, the most negative and most positive values will be the values stored in the respective variables.

Again, the scope of the answer MUST be framed based on what you are currently learning in class.